# How do I separate PHP $_SESSION variables between environments?

Tags: php, session-variables

I am running a test and live site on the same server. They have separate DB’s and live in separate directories, but are both on the same domain.
As the code is the same, so are the variable names, so if I have pages from both environments open at once the values get shared.  How can I isolate my $_SESSION variables to its own distinct environment?

Comment: consider adding your code example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027732/preventing-session-conflicts-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give your session a name before starting it

```
session_name('PROJECT1');
session_start();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027732/preventing-session-conflicts-in-php

Answer (score 0):

you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] variable to check which request is currently being served and then put condition of session variable using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

like this

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "abc.com"){

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027732/preventing-session-conflicts-in-php